# How to recover ssh key for an Ubuntu Server on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys

I've recently resumed working on a webapp for my startup and I've got access to 3 of the 4 SSH keys I need to access my 4 EC2 instances (Ubuntu 19).  The problem is that I can't currently retrieve the 4th SSH key.

Info:

- All 4 EC2 instances are happily running
- The 4th EC2 instance is running MySQL
- The 4th EC2 instance has an AMI image (which contains the SSH key)

Long story short, I need to organise some data recovery in order to obtain the 4th SSH key so I'm just trying to save time by retrieving the SSH key quicker.

Any useful ideas would be gratefully received.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to "recover" the key. That's what makes it secure.

However, you can generate a *NEW* key and put it on the instance.

The **new keypair** can be created in the EC2 management console or [Create a key pair using a third-party tool and import the public key to Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/create-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws).

The harder part is getting the new keypair onto the instance. First, let's recap how SSH authentication works...

When a user logs into a Linux computer using SSH, they specify the **private half of a keypair**. When the computer receives the SSH login request, it looks in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and attempts to find a matching **public key**. If a match is found, the login is permitted. Therefore, your quest is to get the public half of the new keypair into the `authorized_keys` file for the appropriate user (which is typically `ec2-user` so the file is located at `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

One easy option is to use **EC2 Instance Connect** from the EC2 console. However, it requires some software to be installed on the instance (which is standard with Amazon Linux) and some permissions to be assigned to the IAM Role associated with the instance. EC2 Instance Connect works by 'pushing' a temporary keypair to the instance and then establishes an SSH connection. You can then use that connection to run commands on the instance (such as adding a key to the `authorized_keys` file).

If the instance **does not meet the requirements** for EC2 Instance Connect (eg it doesn't have the software installed), then the typical process is:

- **Stop** the 'current' instance and **Detach** the Amazon EBS boot volume ('original volume')
- **Launch a new EC2 instance**, then **Attach** the 'original volume' to this instance as an additional Amazon EBS volume. This will give you access to the volume from the 'new instance'
- **Login** to the 'new instance', navigate to the 'original volume' and modify the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file
- Put things back to normal:

  - **Stop** the 'new instance'
  - **Detach** the 'original volume' from the 'new instance'
  - **Attach** the 'original volume' back onto the 'original instance'
  - **Start** the 'original instance'

You will find more-detailed instructions at: [I've lost my private key. How can I connect to my Linux instance?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#replacing-lost-key-pair)

By the way, you can always add or replace keypairs on instances with your personal keypair. For example, you might generate a 'chris keypair'. You can then copy the public half of the keypair to the `authorized_keys` file on each of those instances. This way, you can use the SAME keypair to access each instance. Better yet, each person who is entitled to access the instances could generate their own keypair. That way, if somebody leaves the company, you can remove their keypairs from the instances without impacting how *you* login to them. Or, better yet, connecting to your corporate LDAP or Active Directory to properly manage access to resources.